# Why the output varies for the same input in this Java program?

Tags: java

```
package mk;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class My {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String a,b="mni nk";
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        a=in.next();
        System.out.println(a.replaceAll(" ", ""));
        System.out.println(b.replaceAll(" ", ""));
        if(a.replaceAll(" ","").equalsIgnoreCase(b.replaceAll(" ",""))) 

            System.out.println("True");

}
}
```

output:

```
mni nk
mni
mnink
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`: `next()` only reads one token, so the value of `a` is `"mni"` (as in the output), not `"mni nk"`.